# App crashes when Mongoose can't find the item

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to handle that when mongoose can't find the item, it causes crash my app. I want to show a 404 error page.

Here's the code.

```
  try {
    let theBeverage = Product.findOne({ _id: beverageId });
    await theBeverage.then((data) => (theBeverage = data));
    res.render("menuetail.ejs", { theBeverage });
  } catch (error) {
    res.render("404.ejs").status(404);
  }
```

I expect that it returns a 404 page.

Answer (score 2):

When you are using async await you should not use `then`

Try this:

```
try {
  const theBeverage = await Product.findOne({ _id: beverageId });      
  res.render("menuetail.ejs", { theBeverage });
} catch (error) {
  res.render("404.ejs").status(404);
}
```